# changing font size of `UITextView` same like `UILabel's` setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I want to change font size of the `UITextView` as per text length. So if the text length is very big than Table cell then font size should become smaller. I can use `UILabel's` setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth which will work fine but as to keep the project code with minimal changes i don't want to change it to `UILabel`. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To make a dynamically sizing UITextView inside a UITableViewCell,

- Add a UITextView to a UITableViewCell and add constraint to the sides
- Set the UITextView's scrollEnabled property to NO.

Use AutoDimension property -

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150;
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

If UITextView not editable that's it you need to do.

If you’re allowing users to edit the UITextView, you also need to:
Implement the textViewDidChange method of the UITextViewDelegate
    protocol as below -

```
 -(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView;
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: I dont want to change size of the `UITextView`. I want to change font size of the `UITextView`. I don't know if what you have suggested will do as per my need but ill try.